# the password reset link lifetime not expires in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8

I created a localized copy of ResetPassword.php, redefined the `sendPasswordResetNotification ()` method in `app\user`. In general, I did everything according to the rule (I think so))). All the rules, sends a letter to the mail but there is only one problem. This link does not expire. by default there is 60 minutes, after which the link should be destroyed. But this does not happen. Below my code will be grateful for any help.

```php
 <?php

namespace App\Notifications;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notification;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage;

class mytelresetpassword extends Notification
{
    use Queueable;

    /**
     * Create a new notification instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($token)
    {
        //
        $this->token = $token;
    }

    /**
     * The callback that should be used to build the mail message.
     *
     * @var \Closure|null
     */
    public static $toMailCallback;

    /**
     * Get the notification's delivery channels.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return array
     */
    public function via($notifiable)
    {
        return ['mail'];
    }

    /**
     * Get the mail representation of the notification.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return \Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage
     */
    public function toMail($notifiable)
    {
        if (static::$toMailCallback) {
            return call_user_func(static::$toMailCallback, $notifiable, $this->token);
        }

   $time = ['count' => config('auth.passwords.'.config('auth.defaults.passwords').'.expire')];
   $time = $time['count'];

        return (new MailMessage)
                    ->subject('Şifrənin Dəyişdirilməsi')
                    ->line('Hesabınızdan şifrə yeniləmə tələbi aldığımız üçün bu mail sizə göndərilib.')
                    ->action('Şifrəni Yenilə', url(config('app.url').route('password.reset', ['token' => $this->token, 'email' => $notifiable->getEmailForPasswordReset()], false)))
                    ->line('Bu link '.$time.' dəqiqə müddətində keçərlidir, bu müddət bitdikdən sonra deaktiv olunacaq!')
                    ->line('Şifrə dəyişməyi tələb etməmişsinizsə,   "Şifrəni Yenilə"  düyməsini klikləməyə ehtiyac  yoxdur.');
    }

    /**
     * Get the array representation of the notification.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($notifiable)
    {
        return [
            //
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Set a callback that should be used when building the notification mail message.
     *
     * @param  \Closure  $callback
     * @return void
     */
    public static function toMailUsing($callback)
    {
        static::$toMailCallback = $callback;
    }
}
```

in `app\user`:

```
public function sendPasswordResetNotification($token)
    {
        $this->notify(new mytelresetpassword($token));
    }
```

Comment: In **config/auth.php** you can change the expire time of reset password according to your requirements. By default it set to `'expire' => 60` minutes

Comment: yes there are 60 minutes, no need to change the minut 60 minutes are enough, but it just doesn’t work

Comment: You want to add expire time in password reset link?

Answer (score 0):

I propose adding a few lines in your ResetPasswordController.php:

```
public function showResetForm(Request $request, $token = null)
{
    $email = $request->email;

    if (!$token)
        return redirect()->route('login');

    if (!$email)
        return redirect()->route('login');

    $reset = PasswordReset::where('email', $request->input('email'))->first();

    if (!$reset)
        return redirect()->route('login');

    $expiry  = Carbon::now()->subMinutes( 60 );

    if ($reset->created_at <= $expiry) {
        return redirect()->route('login');
    }

    return view('auth.passwords.reset')->with(
        ['token' => $token, 'email' => $request->email]
    );
}
```